# Calculate the "betweeness centrality" in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Question**

I have a table **MyRelations** that holds the Many-To-Many relationships for my table **MyAccounts**. Now I need to determine the **betweeness centrality** between **MyAccounts** for all rows.
How can I find this using pure SQL ?

**Model**

- Table **MyAccounts** : Id, Name
- Table **MyRelations** : Id,ForeignKeyA, ForeignKeyB

**Additional**

I am trying to achieve this with PostGreSQL

Any ideas ? Google seems to be not helping with straight forward examples to base myself upon.

Comment: It is possible to implement Diekstra algorithm using recursive CTE (`WITH RECURSIVE`). On top of it `betweeness centrality` is trivial to calculate. The problem - SQL is not a good fit for the problem. It is way easier to do it with other languages.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko : Well yeah I tried to use CTE (with Recursive) but I couldn't get any correct result out of it, so maybe I am doing it all wrong. Using another language on top of it is currently not possible due the Requirements. EDIT : I can try to formulate the ruff query that I was stuck with.